# Install PHP 7.2 on Fedora 30 after it's auto updated to PHP 7.3.8 via DNF

Tags: php, magento2, fedora

Magento 2.3 runs on PHP 7.2.x but no later. I've done a DNF update on a Fedora 30 server which just bumped PHP to 7.3.8, so the Magento install is now borked. How can I slightly downgrade (!) the PHP version to get it back into compatibility? I don't mind clobbering the PHP install totally, or running these variants simultaneously, but searching for ways to do either is drawing a blank.

Come to think of it, I'd like to know how to stop this happening in future since Magento does seem to be a little behind the release PHP versions, which means it will probably just keep happening.

Comment: can you try yum downgrade? https://access.redhat.com/solutions/29617

Comment: That looked promising, until ...

[carl@nexus bin]# dnf downgrade php-7.2
Last metadata expiration check: 0:24:04 ago on Mon 12 Aug 2019 16:00:54 BST.
No package php-7.2 available.
Error: No packages marked for downgrade.
[carl@nexus bin]# dnf downgrade php7.2
Last metadata expiration check: 0:24:21 ago on Mon 12 Aug 2019 16:00:54 BST.
No package php7.2 available.
Error: No packages marked for downgrade.